# Centering bootstrap 3 tabs horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I added `center-vertically` to `<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">` in the services section but this doesn't seem to work. I tried a couple of other things as well but to no success.

`center-vertically` contains:

```
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Check out the [live version here](http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/) (just go to the services section to check out the tabs) if you inspect element on the column the tabs are in you will see a little bit of extra space on the right.

Comment: are you trying to center vertically or horizontally? You say vertical but you are complaining about extra space on the right. If you clarify what you are trying to correct little further, I can take a look

Comment: _edit_ ok so I am an idiot I was trying to center it horizontally with my vertical centering css, but I got to this point cause I tried everything else. Sorry about the confusion, need in centered horizontally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parent should have:

```
parent {
  display: table;
}
```

child:

```
child {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto; // if you want horizontal centering too
}
```

**UPDATE**

To horizontally center your UL inside of the column:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="display: inline-block;margin: 0 auto;">
```

Your UL has full width. *display: inline-block* will trim it and *margin: 0 auto* will center it inside the parent.

Comment: I tried adding `.services .container { display: table; }` with `<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 center-vertically">` but this did not work, this should work it doesn't make sense

Comment: Yeah np if you click services in navigation on live link (#section5) I have `<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 center-vertically">`which consists of my tabs, and in the parent container I have `.services .container { display: table; }` but if you inspect element on my column I still have extra space on the right

Comment: <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 center-vertically"> looks centered in Chrome. Do you mean the space to the right of the last tab within your ul?

Comment: Yes looks like it but it is not, the space is in `<ul class=​"nav nav-tabs">​` I believe, you can see if you inspect element in chrome

Comment: Ok so it seems inline block did its job but margin: 0 auto did not center it in the parent, updated preview if you want to take a look

Comment: ```<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3" style="text-align: center;">```